# extract year, month, day column from date column with class factor using lubridate

Tags: r, lubridate

[image]

In this table I have a column named Date and I want to add 3 more columns as Year, Month, and Day and extract the information from the Date column itself but the class of the Date column is factor.

How can I do that in R using `lubridate`.

Comment: Try `v1 <- mdy_hm(df1$Date); transform(df1, Year = year(v1), Month = month(v1), Day = day(v1))`

Answer (score 3):

Using `lubridate`, we can use `mdy_hm` to convert to datetime object and then extract the `year`, `month`, and `day`

```
library(lubridate)
v1 <- mdy_hm(df1$Date)
df2 <- transform(df1, Year = year(v1), Month = month.abb[month(v1)], Day = day(v1))

df2
#              Date Year Month Day
#1   3/30/2008 0:04 2008   Mar  30
#2 10/15/2009 10:15 2009   Oct  15
```

#### data

```
df1 <- data.frame(Date = c("3/30/2008 0:04", "10/15/2009 10:15"))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Akrun, its working but if I want to convert that Date column into a Date fromat without creating a new column as mentioned by you 'v1' , how to do that, if u can help please...

Comment: @user8335527  Then just do `df1$Date <- as.Date(df1$Date, "%m/%d/%Y")`

Comment: but in Date column time is also there that's why its not working.. I'm getting error: "Error in as.Date.default(BAF_Prod_ChartApr08_Jun17, "%m/%d/%y") : 
  do not know how to convert 'BAF_Prod_ChartApr08_Jun17' to class “Date”

Comment: @user8335527  Based on the example you showed in image and the one I showed in 'data' it is working for me

Comment: A slight refinement, can do `month(v1, abbr=TRUE)`, instead of `month.abb[month(v1)]`